# Is there a way to fix AfterimageCompensationService: Read COPR_ROI or Luminance Data is Out of Bound issue

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

I have been running my Android application and sometimes I run into this error after repeated sliding of a slider in the application.

The native error is as follows:

```
05-06 10:29:25.058  1333  4240 W System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/lcd/panel/copr_roi (No such file or directory)
05-06 10:29:25.058  1333  4240 W System.err:    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
05-06 10:29:25.058  1333  4240 W System.err:    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:200)
05-06 10:29:25.058  1333  4240 W System.err:    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:150)
05-06 10:29:25.058  1333  4240 W System.err:    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
05-06 10:29:25.058  1333  4240 W System.err:    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
05-06 10:29:25.058  1333  4240 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.hardware.display.AfterimageCompensationService.readStrFromFile(AfterimageCompensationService.java:758)
05-06 10:29:25.058  1333  4240 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.hardware.display.AfterimageCompensationService.getCoprRoiNBrightness(AfterimageCompensationService.java:590)
05-06 10:29:25.059  1333  4240 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.hardware.display.AfterimageCompensationService.-wrap0(Unknown Source:0)
05-06 10:29:25.060  1333  4240 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.hardware.display.AfterimageCompensationService$AfcThread.run(AfterimageCompensationService.java:421)
05-06 10:29:25.062  1333  4240 W System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/lcd/panel/brt_avg (No such file or directory)
05-06 10:29:25.062  1333  4240 W System.err:    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
05-06 10:29:25.062  1333  4240 W System.err:    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:200)
05-06 10:29:25.062  1333  4240 W System.err:    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:150)
05-06 10:29:25.063  1333  4240 W System.err:    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
05-06 10:29:25.063  1333  4240 W System.err:    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
05-06 10:29:25.063  1333  4240 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.hardware.display.AfterimageCompensationService.readStrFromFile(AfterimageCompensationService.java:758)
05-06 10:29:25.063  1333  4240 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.hardware.display.AfterimageCompensationService.getCoprRoiNBrightness(AfterimageCompensationService.java:613)
05-06 10:29:25.063  1333  4240 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.hardware.display.AfterimageCompensationService.-wrap0(Unknown Source:0)
05-06 10:29:25.063  1333  4240 W System.err:    at com.samsung.android.hardware.display.AfterimageCompensationService$AfcThread.run(AfterimageCompensationService.java:421)
05-06 10:29:25.063  1333  4240 I AfterimageCompensationService: Read COPR_ROI or Luminance Data is Out of Bound - 0
```

I have searched google but have not found any solutions or similar problems posted other than some logfile that was posted on unreal engine

Comment: I get the same error on a Samsung Tablet